# two-stage submission of django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a django model that looks something like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    a = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=33, blank=False)
    c = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
```

and a corresponding form

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Asking the user to fill in the form is a two phase process.  First I ask whether `a` is True or False.  After a submit (would be better maybe with ajax, but keep it simple at first) I can fill in a dropdown list with choices for `b` and decide whether or not to show `c` as an option.  No need to show `a` as a choice any more, it's descriptive text.

So I want to present a form twice, and the same model is behind it, slowly being filled in.  First choose `a`, then be reminded that `a` is `True` and be asked about `b` and `c`.  Or that `a` is `False` and be asked about only `b`.  After submitting this second form, I save the object.

I'm not clear how best to do this in django.  One way is to make two separate form classes, one of which has hidden fields.  But if the same model is behind both and the model has required fields, I'm anticipating this will get me in trouble, since the first form won't have satisified the requirement that `b` be non-empty.  In addition, there's a small amount of fragility introduced, since updating the model requires updating two forms (and a probably at least one view).

Alternatively, I could use non-model forms and have full freedom, but I'd love to believe that django has foreseen this need and I can do it easier.

Any suggestions on what the right idiom is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Form Wizard from form-tools for that: https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html

It works rather simple by defining multiple forms and combining them. Then in the end, you can use the data to your liking with a custom done() form. The docs tell you everything. You can use JS to hide some of your fields for the super quick approach (utilize localStorage for example).